# Slide in animation between fragments, with the same background color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-animation

I have two fragments, Fragment A and Fragment B, and I use slide_in animation between them. But the main background color in those fragment are white, because of that, slide animation doesn't look good, so I want to make Fragment A darker during the slide_in animation. How cam I achieve this?
Here is the slide_in_right.xml animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

I don't know how to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xml to manually set values to your slide_in animation. Please read more about objectAnimator for modification.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="500"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:duration="3000"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:duration="3000"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
        android:valueType="colorType"
        android:valueFrom="@color/fromColor"
        android:valueTo="@color/toColor"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).